# I want to change change the arrangement of the grid of posts displayed by the theme on the Search page (read the description for better understanding)

Tags: css

i have a theme called Hueman installed on my Wordpress. I have the free version of the theme installed. Now whenever i search using the default search of Wordpress it displays the result in a grid layout with 2 posts in a row with the images having a weird aspect ratios and cropping. I changed the size of those images to (width 200px and height 290px) to avoid it being cropped and i disabled excerpt.
Now those images are smaller and occupy less space but still it is displaying only 2 posts in a row with the rest of the space being empty (as shown in the screenshot below)
[image: image of website with 2 post in a row] 
As this was looking ugly i put float:none in my custom CSS. This allowed me to have more than one post in a row but it made it unorganized and some of the post appear in random positions as seen in the screenshot below.
 [image: 1st Screenshot of unorganized layout]
[image: 2nd Screenshot of unorganized layout]
I want to make this into an organized grid where elements in the next row start from the left and don't pop up randomly to any location.
Below are the screenshots of the code of the page when i use inspect element in chrome.
[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]
[image: screenshot 3]
[image: screenshot 4]
[image: screenshot 5]

Comment: If you're familiar with CSS you could create a Child Theme and add some CSS that creates however many columns and rows you desire. Although you're using WordPress, this type of question is not really considered on-topic here because the focus is on coding functionality, not styling - things that anyone could apply to any WP site, not specific to a particular theme or plugin. You might be able to get some CSS help over on the main StackExchange site.

Answer (score 0):

Try using flexbox, try adding the following in your custom CSS.  Here is more info on [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and a [flexbox generator](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) you can play around with.

```
    .grid-wrapper {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
```